# Why does Redo.Last command not work after executing a modeling command via Py script?

Tags: python

I noticed that when you write an operator lets say to extrude or crease an edge
and as the last step add the code for calling the F6 Redo.Last command, everything will be executed and work besides the F6 menu.

It seems that there is an issue calling the F6 from inside a script while calling it via pressing a button on a pie menu works:

[image]

```
pie.operator("screen.redo_last")
```

The idea or goal is to via script edge crease and then instantly call the redo.last command so you can via a better UI adjust the edge slide value.

```
#Set Edge Crease
class SetOrigin(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "set.edgecrease"
    bl_label = "Set Edge Crease"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        bpy.ops.transform.edge_crease(value=0)
        bpy.ops.screen.redo_last()
        return{'FINISHED'}
```

Any idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: this doesn't fix the main problem, (turtles all the way down) but you need to use parentheses on direct operator calls `bpy.ops.screen.redo_last()`

Comment: I fixed the error but narrowed it down to that as it seems the screen.redo_last() works as a pie command but not as a bpy.ops inside a script.